# Calculator Regex Decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a regular expression that can work in a simple calculator:

Right now I have:  `this.field.value.match(/\./))`

My problem is I can only insert one decimal at a time:

eg: 
**2.5 + 2** OR
**3 + 3.55**

I would like the ability to have the option of adding 2.5 + 2.5. The point is, I'm trying to prevent someone from typing 2.5.5.5 + 5

Comment: If it's a calculator, you'll also need to process things like `0.1 - (1.2+3.4) + -5.6e-7`. The parenthesis can be nested and there are unary operators, making regex an inappropriate tool for this in much the same way as it's inappropriate to parse html using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
/ *(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+) *\+ *(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+) */
```

Matches

```
1   + 1
1.0 + 1.0
1.  + 1.
0.1 + 0.1
.1  + .1
```

and so on.

Doesn't match

```
.  + .
1  +
.1 +
1. +
```

and so on...

Also matches whitespace between + sign and on beginning and end of input.

Answer (score 2):

For `2.5 + 2.5`, you can use:

```
/[0-9]\+\.?[0-9]* + [0-9]\+\.?[0-9]*/
```

Anyway, keep in mind that regex cannot fully parse arithmetic expression because it is a [context free grammar](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/grammars/cfg.html) and regex haven't got the expressive power to cover that.

So, my regex is just a very ad-hoc suggestion for your case. You can for sure further improve it.

Comment: You need to at least escape the `+`, and of course this only works for one specific example; JREAM wants a "simple calculator"...

Answer (score 1):

```
\d*(?:\.\d)?\d*\s*\+\s*\d*(?:\.\d)?\d*
```

matches

```
12+2.4
.34 +2
12.34 + .34
```

but does not match

```
12.34.2 + 2
12.+3
```

Do the same for the other binary operators you need for multiplication, division, etc.

Comment: `12.` is the same as `12.0`, so it's a valid input.

Comment: Depends on your notation. If you want to permit trailing periods, replace (?:\.\d)? with \.?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^\s*([+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.\d+))\s*([-+\/*])\s*([+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.\d+))\s*$/
     ^--------- group 1 ---------^   ^group2 ^   ^--------- group 3 ---------^
```

the capture groups :

```
group 1 will contain the first operand (maybe signed)
group 2 will contain the operator (-,+,/,*)
group 3 will contain the second operand (maybe signed)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be going about this the wrong way.  Instead of trying to regex every possible combination of acceptable entries, juse ensure the input contains only valid characters and then try to calculate a value:

```
var result;
if(/^[0-9+\-()^*/ .]+$/.test(this.field.value))
  try{result=new Function("return "+s+";")();}catch(e){};
if(result==undefined) /* there is a problem */ else /* OK */
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if you do a simple calculator, you'll have to better define what simple means for you. For me. it means that you support standard operations (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`), parenthesis `()` integers and floats.

The solution is : there is no simple way! My advice : to evaluate it, you'll have to parse it : reducing each "number" to a check is easy `(\d+|\d*\.\d+)`, but checking the whole structure is hard with a regex (meaning, you'll end up with something super complex and new corner cases each time)

Another simple solution : check if it's not too risky (e.g. matches `^[\d.+*/()]*$`) and try to `eval`-uate it.

If your simple is simpler than mine, you might find a regex, but that's definitely not the best path (it's a bit ilke trying to parse html with regex : you need a contextual parser)